# "TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float" when drawing 2d histogram using matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, interpolation

I made 2D histogram using `matplotlib.pyplotlt.hist2d()` but since the function `hist2d()` does not inherently have the option for interpolation(smoothing), I tried to use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`.

The following is part of my code:

```
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.set_title('Joint Distribution of NND for San Ramon Earthquakes')
h=ax.hist2d(T,D,30,density=True)
ax.imshow(h, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar(h[3],ax=ax)
```

This gives the error saying `TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float.` I searched for the similar examples but I could not figure out what is the problem with my code.

How can I solve this problem?
OR is there alternative way for 2d histogram interpolation without using `imshow()`?

The plot I generated without interpolation is like the following:

[image]

Comment: did you try increasing the number of bins of the histogram instead of interpolation?

Comment: @Matts Yes I tried it, but that reduces the density difference between each bins so I found out that the color distribution is optimal for 30 bins. I just want to smooth the color distributions in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hist2d` matplotlib function returns the binned 2D array, but also the `xedges` and `yedges`, check the [docs here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html). You may want to try:

```
ax.imshow(h[0], interpolation='nearest')
```

Comment: I modified it and there is no more error but interpolation does not work.

Comment: It should work, maybe you can try to use `interpolation="bicubic"` to see if you get a smoother result. Moreover, I would create use a new axis to plot the smooth version, otherwise, they are plotted one on top of the other

Comment: As you mentioned, I could not recognize the smoothing effect because two plots were overlaid.

Comment: But if I add a new axis and draw the plot with imshow(), the numbers of x and y axes become weird.

Comment: Yes, `imshow` doesn't know abount the binning. You need to explicitely set the extent of the plot using the [extent argument](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html)

Comment: It seems that imshow() naturally converts the axes scales to the number of bins. I solved the problem by setting the option 'extent' by the xedges and yedges. It seems that this is the best what I can do. Thanks for the advice!